Remove procedural generated Gameobject
I try to create a script generated dungeon. If a corridor runs alongside a room, all tiles on the adjacent wall are replaced by archways. This is not intended.
The generated rooms have consecutive IDs. The same applies to the individual walls. EG: Room_1 consists of FrontWall_1, BackWall_1, RightWall_1,...
How can I change my script so that only one tile per wall is replaced by a doorway?

Thanks for your help!
The part where I want to destroy only one wall tile:
        GameObject wallToDestroy = null;
        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(doorPosition, 1f);
        bool wallDestroyed = false;

        foreach (var collider in colliders)
        {
            if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Wall" && !wallDestroyed && collider.transform.position == doorPosition)
            {
                wallToDestroy = collider.gameObject;
                Destroy(wallToDestroy);
                wallDestroyed = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        GameObject door = Instantiate(doorPrefab, doorPosition, doorRotation);
        door.name = $"{doorName}_{roomID}";
    }


What is your actual question?

@JeanotZubler My question is, how can I change my script so that only one tile per wall is replaced by a doorway.

I solved it. I created a HashSet which stores all processed walls and checks against this HashSet before removing a walltile.

Yay data structures!
